# How to output an empty string if date is '0000-00-00' in angular

Tags: angularjs

The following line outputs the string **"30.11.-0001"** in case the date is "0000-00-00".

```
{{ payment.pay_date | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy' }}
```

How do I make it output a blank string in case the date is "0000-00-00"? (if possible, without using if clauses or directives)

Comment: 0000-00-00 - is not a valid date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a custom filter , so its reusable in your app

for example,

```
app.filter('hideIfEmpty', function($filter) {
    return function (dateString, format) {
        if(dateString === '0000-00-00') {
            return "";
        } else {
            return $filter('date')(dateString, format.toString());
        }
    };
});
```

you can use this by

```
{{ payment.pay_date | hideIfEmpty: 'dd.MM.yyyy' }}
```

if date is equals to `'0000-00-00'` then return a empty string , or you can return something u like, if is not equals to `'0000-00-00'` then format the date according to the format and return.

here is the [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szy90yn2/1/) (its not output something because filter return empty string `""` use a correct date and test to check. :) )

Comment: its glad to help you :)

Answer (score 5):

The code above has some syntax error. Please try this one. This is perfect and it worked for me very well.

```
((dtItem.DueDate !== '0001-01-01T00:00:00') ? (dtItem.DueDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy') : '' )
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what pay_date is exactly so one of these should probably work:

```
{{ payment.pay_date ? payment.pay_date | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy' : '' }}

{{ (payment.pay_date !== '0000-00-00') ? payment.pay_date | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy' : ''  }}
```